# where to find the original cpp file of ROS navigation package on my computer?

Tags: navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am new to ROS and I am now trying to make some modifications on the original cpp files of base_local_planner, navigation package. I can find the header files such as trajectory.h, but really have no idea about where to find the original cpp files such as trajectory.cpp on my computer, even if I can find original code on github. Are there anybody who know the location of the cpp files?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/266850/where-to-find-the-original-cpp-file-of-ros-navigation-package-on-my-computer?/) by [jla555](https://answers.ros.org/users/31272/jla555/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2017-07-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Assuming that you are using Ubuntu and installed ROS following the [instructions on the wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Installation/Ubuntu), the sources are not installed in your computer. Just the binaries.

If you want to modify the code on base_local_planner, you will have to clone the source code from the [github repository](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/tree/kinetic-devel/base_local_planner) into your workspace, do your modifications and compile.

Hope this helps

---

Originally posted by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) with karma: 5625 on 2017-07-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1